# Java MySQL query issue

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-error-1045

SO my query will not properly work.  also i understand that since i am not using prepared statements that could possibly cause mySQL injections.  moving forward, the issue every time i run this i get an error. 
also just a heads up this is for a school assignment - aka im sure my coding style is probably subpar at best but i am working on it!!!

```
public  String newEmpInsert() {
    return newEmpInsert;
}
private String newEmpInsert = "INSERT INTO empInfo"
   + "(firstName, lastName, SSN, address, salary, pin, empLevel, contactInfo) "
   + "VALUES ('"+firstName+"', '"+lastName+"', '"+SSN+"', '"+address+"', '"+salary+"'," 
   + "'"+pin+"', '"+empLevel+"', '"+contactInfo+"')";
```

all of the variables that are being used to are set from getters and setters within the class the middle man code is below

```
    public void newEmpInsert() {

    // SQL Connection
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = MySQL_connection_test.getConnection();
        // Create a statement
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.executeQuery(queries.newEmpInsert());

    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("--------->>Invalid query!!!!<<--------------");
        System.out.println("Your query has an error, please try again!!");
    }

    // Close the connection
    //VERY IMPORTANT!!
    finally {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            System.out.println("Database closed");
    }
}
```

and i am sure that the variables are getting set properly because in my main i did the following...

```
public class TESTPACKAGE {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //declare a new instance of the procedures
    SqlProcedures procedures = new SqlProcedures();

    procedures.queries = new Queries();

    //use the setters
    procedures.queries.setFirstName("Anthony");
    procedures.queries.setLastName("inner");
    procedures.queries.setSSN(123451235);
    procedures.queries.setAddress("1300 S Farmview");
    procedures.queries.setSalary(18.00);
    procedures.queries.setPin(1234);
    procedures.queries.setEmpLevel(2);
    procedures.queries.setContactInfo("1254569133");


    System.out.println(procedures.queries.getFirstName());
    System.out.println(procedures.queries.getLastName());
    System.out.println(procedures.queries.getSSN());
    System.out.println(procedures.queries.getAddress());
    System.out.println(procedures.queries.getSalary());
    System.out.println(procedures.queries.getPin());
    System.out.println(procedures.queries.getEmpLevel());
    System.out.println(procedures.queries.getContactInfo());



    //execture a query 
    procedures.newEmpInsert();





}
```

}

when i run the getters to ensure that everything is getting set properly it retuns properly..  Please help as this is driving me crazy!!!

if you need any more code let me know and i will include it.  i think that i included everything that is needed.

again thank you all for the help

Comment: you need to use single quote for all the string values as `'"+firstName+"'`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty answer should work (you have to do it for all string typed attributes). Further generating an SQL statement using string concatenation is not recommended since it opens up SQL injection possibility; use Prepared Statements instead. Hibernate is the widely used mechanism when dealing with databases.

Comment: @AmilWaduwawara I agree with you !!

Comment: added single quotes still an error

Comment: What exception type/message are you getting? NullPointerException or some kind of SQLException?

Comment: Driver Loaded.
--------->>Invalid query!!!!<<--------------
Your query has an error, please try again!!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at happy_go_lucky.SqlProcedures.newEmpInsert(SqlProcedures.java:49)
 at happy_go_lucky.TESTPACKAGE.main(TESTPACKAGE.java:44)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

that is the output.  the error on SqlProcedures line 49 is the
 
   conn.close();

the error on TESTPACKAGE line 44 is the method im calling from the main to execute the query

Comment: @Ainnera I mean the _real_ error, not the one you're printing yourself on any exception. Outputting `e.getMessage()` on the caught exception should show it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson sorry for the delay

    java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:502)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1565)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute an `INSERT` query using [`executeQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) which is for queries returning results;

In other words;

```
stmt.executeQuery(queries.newEmpInsert());
```

should instead use [`executeUpdate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String));

```
stmt.executeUpdate(queries.newEmpInsert());
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! that worked.  im still getting errors but i should be able to take it from here!  just MySql error like "default value" and what not.  again thank you.  if i could up vote i would